# Set Class through first getting class from a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a method that tells me what class the object at that indexPath should be (based off of an array with strings);

However this throws an **error**

> "Use of undeclared identifier 'instanceCell'

```
Class companyCellClass = [HomePageFlagIndexing tableCellClassForIndexPath:indexPath];
    companyCellClass *instanceCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[HomePageFlagIndexing getIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath]forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Is there a way to set the class programmatically like this?

Comment: did you register cell or nib with identifier?

Comment: yes - it has those - I just need to check the class, set it and then call my methods on it [instanceCell setUpWithType:0];

Answer (score 2):

**companyCellClass** is a Class object and not a Type, change it with **UITableViewCell**.

If you then want to perform any operation which is declared in that class header, first you will have to downcast it to your class manually and do it, or send performSelector.

Comment: If I do that it wont let me call methods on the cell that are unique to the class.
    instanceCell.delegate = self; for instance

Comment: then just create an abstract/parent class for all of them or a Protocol and cast TableViewCell to that type and assign delegate.

Comment: or just change UITableViewCell with id ( without * mark ) and then call [instanceCell  setDelegate:self]

Comment: but then I cant call  instanceCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; for instance on the cell

Comment: then  do as I wrote above

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For each possible identifier in

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[HomePageFlagIndexing getIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath]forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You have to call :

```
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
// or
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

See Apple's Doc
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: